# Closed form expression for a formal power series

Tags: summation, formal-power-series

Is there a closed form expression for the following formal power series $$\large\sum_{k\ge 0}\dfrac{z^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}$$ Till now I have tried in vain finding any progress to simplify this expression. Please help.

Comment: what is the limit of $k$??? infinity or not???

Comment: I thought $k\ge 0$ *implies* $0\le k<\infty$. Is that not standard?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay It does.  Your notation is fine.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks @Dr.MV.

Comment: The equivalent problem is to evaluate the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^k}$$for $|x|>1$.  WA gives a result that depends on the $x$-digamma function $\psi_x$.  So, if you consider that closed-form enough, then you have a way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set:
$$f(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ f(z^2)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{2\cdot 2^k}}{1+z^{2\cdot 2^k}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^{2^{k+1}}}{1+z^{2^{k+1}}}=f(z)-\frac{z}{1+z}.\tag{2}$$
If we further assume:
$$ f(z)=\sum_{m\geq 1} a_m\,z^{m}\tag{3} $$
$(2)$ gives:
$$ a_k = a_{2k}+1,\qquad 0 = a_{2k+1}-1\tag{4} $$
hence:

> $$ f(z) = \sum_{m\geq 1}\left(1-\nu_2(m)\right) z^m\tag{5} $$

where
$$\nu_2(m)=\max\{r\in\mathbb{N}:2^r\mid m\}.$$

Comment: What function is $v_2$ representing here?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: the $2$-adic height, now written.

Comment: For short, the coefficient of $z^m$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ just depends on the number of trailing zeroes in the binary representation of $m$.

Comment: Nice simplification!